# Algorithm for choosing foods based on macro nutrients

Tags: algorithm

I have a big set of of food ingredients, each of which has Protein, Carb and Fat properties. e.g.:

```
Food Name   P    C    F
Food1       10   5    3
Food2        3   10   8
Food3       4    20   5
```

I need to write a function which will look like:

```
private List< Food > CombineFoodsBasedOnMacro(p, c, f)
```

This function should choose and combine a couple of foods, in different amounts, so that when we combine the P, C and F of the chosen foods amounts they are pretty close to the passed p, c, f parameters.

e.g.

```
CombineFoodsBasedOnMacro(45, 40, 20)
```

Acceptable 'answer' could be:

```
4 * Food1 + 1 * Food3
```

Which would amount to total of:

```
P = 44, C = 40, F = 17
```

My question is: what algorithm can I use for such calculation/approximation?

Comment: knapsack? linear programming?

Answer (score 2):

**This problem is NP-Hard**, and is pretty much the generalization of the [Set Cover Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) for multisets rather than sets, and thus there is no known polynomial solution to the problem (and most believe such solution does not exist).

You can use [integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Integer_linear_program_formulation) to try and solve this problem, something like:

```
minimize Sum( x_s) (number of sets), s.t.:
Sum(x_s | for all sets ) #p(s)*x_s >= p // repeat for c,f
x_s = 0 || x_s = 1
```

Note that #p(s) is not a variable, so it's fine for integer linear programming.